# Detect Worklight Server Hostname/IP Address from Worklight Client code

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

For a variety of reasons, I need programatic JavaScript access the the hostname or IP address of the Worklight server from the client code.

For example: 
- I want to pull scripts and resources from the same host as the Worklight server
- I have an out-of-band service on the Worklight host and I want to connect to it

@IdanAdar has said that the address does not exist. I've search the WL object and cannot find it either. See [Can we get the app version and IP address info using worklight api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418352/can-we-get-the-app-version-and-ip-address-info-using-worklight-api).

Note that document.location.hostname is null when running as a native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current workaround is to set the IP Address / hostname as a global variable in my top-level html file. This is not ideal because it causes my sourcecode to have to vary by implementation.

Worklight already has this value externalized in the application-descriptor.xml

The server side API has this exposed in WL.Server.configuration["local.IPAddress"]. I think the client should expose an API similar to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the best option you can develop an adapter that returns the WL.Server.configuration["local.IPAddress"] if available, also could be possible to acces to the IP through the http request.

[Is it possible to access to the HTTPRequest in the worklight adapter implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398609/is-it-possible-to-access-to-the-httprequest-in-the-worklight-adapter-implementat)

I'm not sure if you can invoke adapters before wlCommonInit, if you can not and you need the ip before the common init then this approach is useless.