# Worklight how to retrieve latest app version on server from client side?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I need to compare the current app version with the latest app version deployed on worklight server from both android and ios app.

Did some research and found the link below but the mentioned api only returns current app version.

[Can we get the app version and IP address info using worklight api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418352/can-we-get-the-app-version-and-ip-address-info-using-worklight-api)

Is there any way the mobile client can retrieve the latest app version?

I'm using Worklight version 5.0.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the use case for the client to know that?

Comment: To implement and replace the disable old version feature base on the user requirement.

Comment: I don't understand... with the Remote Disable feature as it is now  you can block any environment and version you'd like, as long as it is deployed to the Worklight Server. For the feature to work, you do not need to know what is the latest version, simply go to the console and disable the version app that is installed on the the device is running. You can customize this remote disable dialog and/or its behavior, see the documentation.

Comment: I go through this link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_create_a_customized_remote_disable_behavior?lang=en, does that support by 5061?

Comment: It would be best to use 5.0.6.2, there it is supported for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comments:

The way you're trying to do this is not the right one IMO.

with the Remote Disable feature as it is now you can block any environment and a specific version of it that you'd like, as long as it is deployed to the Worklight Server.

For the feature to work, you do not need to know what is the latest version; simply go to the console and disable the app version that is installed on the the device. You can customize this remote disable dialog and/or its behavior, see this blog post: [How to Create a Customized Remote Disable Behavior](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_create_a_customized_remote_disable_behavior?lang=en).

The written in the blog post is supported in the latest Worklight versions: 5.0.6.2, 6.0.0.2 and 6.1.0.1.

Comment: Sadly, we are using 5.0.6.1 and is not feasible to upgrade to 5.0.6.2

Comment: Why? The fix containing this is in Worklight Studio, not server. Also, IMO you SHOULD consider upgrading, in order to get the latest fixes, which are many. As well, if you ever have an iOS app, you will need 5.0.6.2 for iOS 7.x fixes too.